# inline block problem on firefox and internet explore

Tags: html, css, xhtml

I am having a difficult time with how ie and firefox are displaying inline-block. I should probably point out that Google chrome displays it as intended..

```
<div class="cell"> 
    <div><img src="images/dftg.jpg" /></div> 
    <p>Sean val</p>
</div>
```

The problem occurs in firefox and ie when i write a longer name in the paragraph above,  in the parapgrah above. in firefox and ie, the cell div moves up thereby making the layout look weird and inconsistent.

```
.cell { 
    display: inline-block;
    display:-moz-inline-stack;
    border: 3px solid #ff0000;
    padding: 7px;
    height: 170px;
    zoom: 1;
    *display: inline;
    _height: 170px;

}

.cell p {
    padding: 10px 25px;
    width: 150px;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're probably having this problem because you haven't specified any `vertical-align`.

Try using this:

```
.cell { 
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    border: 3px solid #ff0000;
    padding: 7px;
    height: 170px;
    zoom: 1;
    *display: inline;
    _height: 170px;
}
```

You can forget about `display: -moz-inline-stack` - that's only for Firefox 2, which has *very, very* low usage.

The article you probably read while "doing research" was this:

http://blog.mozilla.com/webdev/2009/02/20/cross-browser-inline-block/

You should probably read it again, as it does mention using `vertical-align`.

Comment: @thirtydot....thank u so much, it worked like magic....i thought i tried this though :))))

Answer (score 1):

You should check dates on articles you read. Inline-block has been supported since FF3.

> Another obscure-but-useful new feature making its way into Firefox 3 after all the other major browsers support it (mostly) is the inline block. When assigned to an element, a display type of inline-block causes the element to be positioned inline (like a span), but the element's contents are laid out as if the element were a block.

http://ajaxian.com/archives/soft-hyphens-and-inline-block-subtleties-in-firefox-3-rc-1

Anyway, looks like you solved it.